# Difference between $("css selector") and $(By.linkText("text"))?

Tags: css, selenium, automated-tests, selector, selenide

I need to locate a element, I used the following two ways:

```
$("body.c1 div.c1.c2.c3  div.c4   div.c.c7 ul.cc.c6.c8  li.LoginUrl a")
        .click()
```

But I have problem with this way, because some CSS styles will change from time to time. So I switched to the following:

```
$(By.linkText("login")).click()
```

Since login text is always will be appeared even changing in css style.

Problem: Some tests failed when using the second way, although it would have to do the same work as the first way. All tests worked well using first way.

***What is the difference between them?***

**htmL**

```
<body class="c1">

<div class="c1 c2 c3" id="f">
    <div class="c4">
        <div class="c c7">
            <ul class="cc c6 c8" id="x">
                <li class="LoginUrl"><a href="url" onclick="$('#login').modal('show'); return false;">login</a></li>
            </ul> 
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried a less specific CSS path like `$(".classLogin a")`? Usually there is no need to be as specific as your first example.

Comment: yes I tried less css path many times, but it can't find the element unless provide the full path

Comment: Can you provide `HTML` of target element?

Comment: of course, I edited the question.

Comment: @Hana90 Both your selectors work without problem for me on the HTML you have provided. Do you also have an example where the second selector fails?